# Julia sparse matrix

Tags: matrix, julia, sparse-matrix

I have vector `y_vec`, How to convert the vector to a matrix of form `Y_matrix`

```
y_vec = [0; 1; 1; 2; 3; 4]

Y_matrix = [1 0 0 0 0
            0 1 0 0 0
            0 1 0 0 0
            0 0 1 0 0
            0 0 0 1 0
            0 0 0 0 1]
```

So far, I've tried using a for loop.

```
Y_mat = full(spzeros(length(y_vec), length(unique(y_vec))))

for (i,j) in enumerate(1:length(y_vec))
    Y_mat[i, y_vec[j]+1] = 1
end
```

But, there seems to be a problem when `y_vec` is not continuous, say `y_vec` = [0; 1; 1; 2; 3; 4; **8**], using for loop fails !!! How to get around this issue.

Is there a way to solve the above problem using sparse matrix in Julia.

Comment: The problem with not continuous `y_vec` is because there are not enough columns. Changing `Y_mat` initialization to: `Y_mat = full(spzeros(length(y_vec), maximum(y_vec)+1))` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use sparse matrix constructor [`sparse(I,J,V)`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/#sparse-matrix-constructors):

```
y_vec = [0; 1; 1; 2; 3; 4; 8]
I = collect(1:length(y_vec))
J = y_vec+1
V = ones(length(y_vec))
S = sparse(I,J,V)
full(S)

julia> full(S)
7x9 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```